# External Control of File Name or Path security issue

Tags: java, security, veracode

I have a code

```
File file = new File(fileName)
```

This `fileName` i am preparing from other details. However, I am getting

> External Control of File Name or Path

flaw when I submit my code to security scan tool 'Vera Code'.  Can someone please help me how to resolve this.

Comment: Could you please post the content of "filename"?

Comment: This is what i am doing with "fileName"                             fileName= "/" + certificateId + " " + docTypeLongName + "_" + IDGenerator.getFileId()+ extn;

Comment: I assume that the file name is a UNIX file name

Comment: could it be that the extension of the file name is pointing to a 3rd party application (i.e. it is registered to work with the 3rd party application) and because you now want to work with it outside this 3rd party application

Comment: One thing I am courious about is: how is this related to CRLF / newline?

Comment: No extn is the file type. For eg: If i am uploading "Upload.doc" document then the fileName will be like: /58743364 package_20131295643666-850442.docx  So extn over here will be ".docx"

Answer (score 2):

The reported issue means that someone could be able to modify the `fileName` from outside, e.g. by user input or by modifying a configuration file. See also [CWE-73: External Control of File Name or Path](http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/73.html).

This leads to a security flaw where an attacker could gain access to any files on your filesystem and either read files or even overwrite files other than the intended ones.

You need to check what the **source** of the various parts of your `fileName` is. For example, suppose the user is able to provide the `extn` through your web UI. If you use the user input in your application without further validation, the user could be able to access files which he should not:

```
User input: extn="/../etc/passwd"

Resulting fileName: "/certificateId docTypeLongName_FileId/../etc/passwd"
```

To solve this, you can use **validation** to make sure that the input does not contain specific strings like `..`, or you can use **whitelists** (if the possible input range is limited) to make sure that only well known values are submitted.

Comment: Do i need to check only **..** to remove this flaw?

Comment: It might be sufficient in your particular case, but please check out http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/73.html. The "Implementation" phase gives a good overview of implementation strategies. Keep in mind that attackers are creative...